# gcloud discovery api - no nextPageToken for pagination?

Tags: python, pagination, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am currently trying to list out all the disks and images I have on a google compute project:

```
compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute','v1')
resp = compute.instances().list(project=PROJECT_NAME).execute()
items = resp["items"]
# do something with items...
while "nextPageToken" in resp:
    resp = compute.instances().list(project=PROJECT_NAME, pageToken=resp["nextPageToken"])
    items = resp["items"]
    # do something with items...
```

I know for a fact that this is not returning all the images I have. I looked at the output and it was missing a few dozen.

I tried printing:

```
print(list(resp.keys()))
```

And I only ever get these keys:

```
[u'items', u'kind', u'id', u'selfLink']
```

Which means `nextPageToken` was never given to me.

Comment: You mention that you want to list all the images but you use compute.instances() instead of compute.images(), is that just a typo here ?

Comment: Yes, good catch. I actually wanted the same functionality for both images and instances but I only gave the example of instances for brevity

Comment: I just tried both methods on my side, compute.instances().list and compute.images.list(), and it does return all my images / instances. When I set a maxResults to a lower number, I also get a nextPageToken. So I'm guessing your issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

compute.instances.list is zonal. You are probably only getting results for one zone. Try the equivalent in gcloud:

```
gcloud compute instances list --log-http 2>&1 | grep ^GET
```

You'll see a zones list request followed by an instances list request for each of those zones. gcloud / Cloud SDK has a zonal (and regional) aggregator module that encapsulates this and handles pageToken within each zone.